# Upload local file without choose button

Tags: javascript, html, file, file-upload

I have a question regarding upload a file to some server. I understand that due to security issues, web browser does not allow javascript to access user's file directory. So currently my method is to add a choose file button and manually choose a file to upload. I did a lot of research on internet for other alternate approach, but did not find anything useful. Is there any possible way to automate the process of choosing the file? (I only need to upload one file) Like changing web browser setting or attach this file somewhere inside html or any other approach?

Comment: You'll need to add some information on what you've tried already, in code I'm afraid...

Comment: have you thought of drag and drop?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Right now for the html page , I have 
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" single />
<input type="button" value="upload" onclick="uploadFiles()" />
<output id="list"></output>
to choose a file 
And onclick I upload that file to server using restAPI. All of this can working properly. What I need to do now is to automate the choose part

Comment: Both drag/drop and choose file can work, but I need to automate it because I'm doing test automation, so need to get rid of the mouse click/drag part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say but I have tried this in the past and the web-browser does not allow it to be done due to security. Even if you know the filename on the user's computer, the browser will only attach a file object to your `<input type="file" />` element if it was selected via the web-browser's native 'file browser'.  Although this is bad news, this is the right answer.

The security issue is that web-browsers enforce the rule that the user **must** be informed and also initiate the action of the file being attached to form elements in the web-page they are viewing.

This action can only be initiated by the user via the default 'browse' button on the `<input type="file" />` element or a file drag/drop action by the user captured with javascript.

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. I'm quite new to JavaScript and html. Also do not have so much experience in programming. Actually, the major part of my project comes after the uploading. So the upload part is not necessarily inside JavaScript. Is there other alternative languages/approaches I can use to upload file first, and then after uploading finish, triggered the html/JavaScript part to do the rest stuff? Like doing 2 part using different language! And then integrate them together? I'm not sure if it's possible

Comment: @user4613659, I can't write much in the space of this comment box.  But I would have javascript 'listening' for an update by having a setInterval() on my webpage that sends an AJAX request every few seconds to a PHP script on a web-server that any uploaded files would be uploaded to. That PHP script would then basically do a check for a new file to show up on the web-server. The server PHP script would respond to the web-page AJAX request by returning 'false' unless it found a new file, then it would return 'true' and have whatever pertinent info your web-page needed about the uploaded file.

Comment: After more than 5 years is the answer still no..??