# how to automaically upload a file to server (without button) in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I'm newbie at WEb2py so sorry if the question seems simple.

I have a text file which is formed in a computer and I need to upload it to the server (where web2py is running) for further analysis. I **do not** want the user to click a button and upload, etc...

I need it to be done automatically, as the web page is loaded.

Comment: Is this file going to reside at a static location (always in documents/filename.txt?

Comment: Then write the same function to upload the file, but don't attach it to a button and just call it..

Comment: By static you mean on the web server? if so, yes. I'm doing some math manipulations and then export it to amcharts as Json. every time the user launches the web page, it should take the exact same file (I will alter it as needed before hand but the name and location on the desktop computer will remain the same)

Comment: To be clear, the file is on the user's computer (i.e., the same computer as the browser), and when the user loads a particular page, you want the file to be uploaded from the user's computer to the server in the background without the user taking any action or even necessarily being aware that this is happening? If so, think about the security implications of that being possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload local file without choose button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762150/upload-local-file-without-choose-button)